# "Turn in" vs. "Hand in"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

In the context of submitting your work to your boss, which is the right phrase to use 'turn in' or 'hand in'? And why? And how are they used differently in other contexts?

Examples:

> 1. "He always **hands in** his work late."
> 2. "He always **turns in** his work late."

Comment: Which dictionaries did you check? What specific thing(s) about the definitions that you found caused you trouble? The [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english) and many others have phrasal verbs and figures of speech--and example sentences.

Comment: @pazzo: your link seems broken?

Comment: [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/) or [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dictionary.htm), or: [Onelook dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/), which returns results from over a dozen dictionaries..

Comment: Of the top of my head (as an AmE speaker), I'd think that those two usages are in competition with each other, which means that there is a large amount of overlap in usage. There probably are some specific contexts where only one or the other is acceptable. Acceptability might also depend on regional and/or register and/or style considerations. "Hands in" might sometimes have a personal or physical connotation to it, while "Turns in" might be more of a general expression. Maybe someone will write an answer that dives in more deeply into this. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In British English, the correct phrase is *hand in*.

From [Macmillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/hand-in):

> ## hand in
>
> *phrasal verb (transitive)*
>
> 1. to give something to a person in authority
>    *Please hand in your keys when you leave the hotel.*
>    *All essays must be handed in by Tuesday.*

In American English, you can use either hand in, or [turn in](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/turn-in):

> ## turn in
>
> *phrasal verb*
>
> **ᴍᴀɪɴʟʏ ᴀᴍᴇʀɪᴄᴀɴ**
>
> 4. to give something to the person who has officially asked for it or who is in charge
>    **turn in something to someone**: *Mitro turned in his resignation to the President.*

There is a subtle difference between the two - you can *turn something in* only if it has been specifically asked for (you wouldn't normally talk about *turning in your keys* as in the "hand in" example, unless perhaps you mistakenly ran off with them and needed to turn them in later) or you are giving the thing to a superior.

So, for example:

- Please turn in all borrowed equipment
- When I found a stranger's wallet on the street, I handed it in
- I have done my homework, and turned it in

Comment: Downvoter please turn yourself in ;)

Comment: -1 The ODO British & World English dictionary says otherwise.

Comment: @pazzo? As a native BrE speaker, my first thought was "turn in sounds American" before I went and found a corroborating source. Perhaps if you link to the place it says something different (and explain which "otherwise" you mean!), we could clear this up the confusion?

Comment: Yes, ODO BrE has for both *give something to someone in authority*.

Comment: @pazzo I'm not sure if [this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/) is the dictionary you mean when you simply say "ODO BrE" (it was the top result when I Googled for it, but it has the wrong initials), but the only definition it lists for [turn in](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/turn-in?q=turn+in) is to go to bed for the night.

Comment: Yrs that's the dictionary I mean. But just look up *turn* then scroll down to the phrasal verbs.

Comment: [Cambridge BrE dictionary] (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/turn-sth-in).

Comment: @pazzo Hmm. How would you recommend I summarise these different results (you read the part of my answer where Macmillian said it was mainly American, right?) in the answer? The specific example given by the OP sounds American to me with *turn in* (though, of course, it would be understood in the UK nevertheless).

Comment: I think you should identify yourself as a native speaker of British English and state what is appropriate for the context the OP asks about. I will reverse my vote, as I didn't know you were a native speaker, and the dictionaries may or may not give exact examples of turn in/hand in work to an employee. However, it is also the case that usage may  not not be uniform across BrE

Comment: The British National Corpus has 346 instances of *turn in*, but as near as I can tell, they're all false positives (other uses of those two words than we're discussing here), so there were really 0 results for *turn in*.  On the other hand, the BNC has 1248 instances of *hand in*, and although most of those are false positives as well, I was able to find a number of true positives searching through by hand.  I didn't look at all of them, so I'm not sure how many, but it definitely seemed like *hand in* was represented and *turn in* was not.

Answer (score -1):

Macmillan Dictionary says that both have one common meaning.

**[turn in](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/turn-in)**

> *to give something to the person who has officially asked for it or who is in charge*

and...

**[hand in](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/hand-in)**

> *to give something to a person in authority*

If you see the subtlety, the former one is used when someone has **asked** you for something, as in your example. The boss has asked you for that work.

In the latter example, you give something to a person in authority--say--your resignation. They did not ask it, but you submitted and submitted to the higher authority.

Said that, **if we go by MM**, 'turn in' fits in your example. Because it talks about the tasks were allotted to the employees 'he' and 'she'.